# Как получить одно из двух значений Object из Map<String, Object> и поместить его в List<>?

Tags: java, android, list, map

От сервера с помощью Retrofit я получаю данные в виде:

```
{
    "0":
      {"id":"1", "title":"one"},
    "1":
      ("id":"2", "title":"two"}
}
```

Далее успешно сохраняю в Map, где Object сделан из модели:

```
public static Model() {
     String id;
     String title;
}
```

Затем мне нужно взять только один параметр title и его поместить в List<>, который будет помещен далее в ListView и показываться во фрагменте.
Уже долго не могу разобраться, как мне все эти title-s вытащить из map и вставить в list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Map.Entry<String, Object> mp : map.entrySet()) {
        list.add(((Model)mp.getValue()).title);
    }
```

Comment: можно и без кастования, если мапа объявлена с нормальным дженериком )

Comment: Благодарю. Ваш вариант сработал, и вместо Object я подставил свою модельку. Сделал также без кастования.
Правда, на месте list студия делает предупреждение: "Contents of collection 'list' are updated, but never queried'. Я не знаю, что это такое...

Comment: @AntonPankratov, предупреждение говорит, что вы этот `'list'` заполнили и забыли (нигде не обращаетесь к его содержимому).

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list = map.values().stream()
    .map(Model::getTitle)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Ваш вариант я попробывал, но Студия просит обновить версию языка. После обновления Collectors.toList() так и не "засуществовал" у меня.

Comment: А какая версия java и под какую версию Android вы пишете? + В настройка проекта нужно проверить, какая версия проставлена для модуля.